# Multiple list or dictionary?

Tags: c#, arrays, list, dictionary

I'm working in C# in Unity3D. I need a structure to save some values. I need to access that structure by a string index, and the values are GameObjects (but this question applies to any possible value, it's the same). I don't know how many objects I will store on each index, so it can't be an array. 
I thought in a

```
Dictionary<string,List<GameObject>>
```

but it's possible to add items to that list in the same moment that I add the index? Because if I need to fill the list BEFORE add it to the dictionary, I can have X lists and forget about the Dictionary.

What's the best structure to accomplish this?

Comment: `if(dictionary.ContainsKey("MyKey")) { // Update the existing list }else{ // Insert new key with new value }`

Comment: That is when the dictionary has 1 element on each index. I want to have a list on each index. So I have to add it to the list, not to the dictionary.

Comment: No. What you just said is how a dictionary works. I never said anything about not having a list on each index. What's the problem with updating a dictionary by adding elements to the List of a specific key from a dictionary?

Comment: You are thinking on exactly the right lines here. You can add items to the List<T> before or after you add it to the Dictionary, it's a reference to the List so it will work exactly as you expect.

Comment: Use Linq :             Dictionary<string,List<GameObject>> dict = objects.GroupBy(x => x.index, y => y)
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.ToList());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could implement your own multi dictionary

```
public class MultiDictionary<TKey, TValue> : Dictionary<TKey, List<TValue>>
{
    public void Add(TKey key, TValue value)
    {
        if (TryGetValue(key, out List<TValue> valueList)) {
            valueList.Add(value);
        } else {
            Add(key, new List<TValue> { value });
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I'm adding a `Add` method to be able to add a single value automatically without having to deal with lists. The class inherits the original `Add` method that allows you to also add a whole list.

Alternatively you could create a `Dictionary<TKey, HashSet<TValue>>` if you need to add unique values and the order does not matter.